# ABORT: Aborting on channel error line :2076 in Selenium 3.0.0 beta 2

Tags: selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

I have been using Selenium 3.0.0 beta2 with the Firefox 48.0.2 and geckodriverv10.0 for win 64.

The problem is that the browser crashes without closing.

```
>  [Child 10232] ###!!! ABORT: Aborting on channel error.: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp,
> line 2046
```

And it passes the test case.

I tried with FF 46.0.9 as well still gives the same error.

Answer (score 1):

According to the geckodriver [issue #210](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/210), this was caused by mozilla bug [1051567](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1051567) and will not be resolved in FF48. FF49 is recommended.

I was getting this error with FF48.0.2 on OS X 10.11.6 and geckodriver 0.10.0 with Selenium 3.0.0-beta3. I tested with 49.0b9 and still see the error, but only intermittently.  The line number has changed from 2046 to 2052.

Comment: It also appears on 51.0.1 (32-bit)

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by using these versions:

- Firefox Setup 48.0.2 (32bit)
- geckodriver-v0.15.0-win32
- JavaSetup8u121 (32bit)
- selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1